# SO_REUSEADDR seems to hold the value 4

Tags: c, sockets

I've been trying to learn about socket programming using c, and I ran into something that confused me. I wrote this code:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
      int sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
      int opt = 1;

      if(sockfd == -1) {
              printf("socket error\n");
              exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
      }

      if(setsockopt(sockfd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &opt, sizeof(opt))) {
              printf("setsockopt error\n");
              exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
      }

      int getOpt;
      socklen_t  getOptLen = sizeof(getOpt);
      getsockopt(sockfd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &getOpt, &getOptLen);

      printf("%d\n", getOpt);
 }
```

I expected it to print one, because that was the value that I passed to setsockopt, but it's printing 4. Is the boolean value of SO_REUSEADDR stored as 4? Am I using getsockopt incorrectly?

Comment: There's a whole pile of options that can be set true/false by these calls.  It just so happens that the SOL-SOCKET value for SO_REUSEADDR is 00000100B so turning it on sets the option value to 4.

Comment: @MartinJames I can’t follow that. There’s no connection between 00000100B and 4, or the value of SO_REUSEADDR and the bit that it sets in some option word.

Comment: @EJP see sg7 ans. below.  Those opt are just a bitmask of the option values ORed together.  4 as a binary byte is 00000100, though it's prolly an unsigned int, but I was tired of counting 0's.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The value of `SO_REUSEADDR` is `4`.  Or in hexadecimal representation `(0x0004`)

```
#define SO_REUSEADDR    0x0004      /* allow local address reuse */
```

See definition of some other options:

```
/*
 * Option flags per-socket.
 */
#define SO_DEBUG        0x0001      /* turn on debugging info recording */
#define SO_ACCEPTCONN   0x0002      /* socket has had listen() */
#define SO_REUSEADDR    0x0004      /* allow local address reuse */
#define SO_KEEPALIVE    0x0008      /* keep connections alive */
#define SO_DONTROUTE    0x0010      /* just use interface addresses */
#define SO_BROADCAST    0x0020      /* permit sending of broadcast msgs */
#define SO_USELOOPBACK  0x0040      /* bypass hardware when possible */
#define SO_LINGER       0x0080      /* linger on close if data present */
#define SO_OOBINLINE    0x0100      /* leave received OOB data in line */
```

You may want to take a look at this: [socket.h](https://github.com/openbsd/src/blob/master/sys/sys/socket.h) include file.

Comment: This does not directly answer the question.

Comment: Thank you, I'll poke around the socket.h file.

Comment: The link to `socket.h` is dead.

Comment: @hasen Thank you for your comment! I have added new link for socket.h from OpenBSD.

Answer (score 1):

The value of `SO_REUSEADDR` is a boolean.  In C, a boolean has more than one bit, and if any bit is set, it is considered true.  That is, 0 means false and anything else means true.

The fact that you get the number 4 is perhaps a little odd, but just a quirk of the implementation.  Nothing is wrong with your code.  You should not be using the numeric value of `getOpt` other than to check if it is zero or non-zero.

Wild speculation: the implementation might store several boolean socket options in a single integer, with a mapping to say that `SO_REUSEADDR` is bit 2 (which would have the value 4 if set).

Comment: "Nothing is wrong with your code.". If it doesn't error check return value of `getsockopt()` how can we be sure the value in getOpt is valid?

Comment: @spinkus: The possible errors for getsockopt are (1) EBADF/ENOTSOCK, which it can't be, because the fd was checked before, (2) EFAULT, which it can't be because `getOpt` and `getOptLen` are obviously in the address space, (3) EINVAL/ENOPROTOOPT, which it can't be because we already used `setsockopt` with the same SO value.  Therefore, getsockopt should never fail in the code as written.  Still, checking the return value would be a nice touch.

Comment: @spinkus: I have exhaustively enumerated the possible error return codes and why each of them cannot happen given the OP's code.  I agree that checking the return value is a good idea anyway.  Note that the OP's code does not actually connect to anything, so there's no possibility for a network failure to do anything to the socket (for example).

Comment: I think EBADF, and ENOTSOCK are sufficiently vague for a file descriptor to become "invalid" *somehow* or a file descriptor to no longer refer to a "socket" *somehow*, in *some* implementation sometime ever anywhere under some interpretation of those strings of English words.

Comment: @spinkus It can’t be invalid immediately after a successful `setsockopt()`. It would need an intervening `close()`. These ‘string of English words’ refer to the specific implementation which they document.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.

Comment: @EricOseid: You're welcome.  If this addressed your question satisfactorily, you can "accept" it by clicking the checkmark on the left of this answer.  Welcome to SO.

Comment: @JohnZwinck what would be the benefit of holding the options in a single integer? Is it more space efficient?

Comment: @spinkus Oops I didn't realize that I wasn't error checking. If there a specific reason why the function returns 0 on success and -1 on completion? If it returned 1 on success and 0 on failure then my code would be valid.

Comment: @EricOseid: Yes, of course if there are a set of flags, using one bit for each is more space efficient than using one byte or word for each.